# Una tabla por dato Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Estoy tratando de mostrar una tabla por cada dato de mi JSON en angular, pero no se como hacerlo, no se si se tenga que inyectar código HTML desde angular o habrá alguna otra manera.

Mas o menos seria algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí, `this.lst` ya tiene los datos del JSON:

```
getLista(){
  this.apilibreria.getLibreria().subscribe( s => {
    this.lst = s;
  });
}
```

Ahora solo faltaría mostrar una tabla por dato, ayuda por favor, muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vas a tener en tu .ts en tu método `getLista()` los datos que traes desde tu api en un arreglo, en tu caso en `lst`
Suponiendo que tus datos traidos desde el api tienen algo como esto:

```js
 lst = [
    {
      nombre: 'Carlos',
      nacimiento: '1994'
    },
    {
      nombre: 'Manuel',
      nacimiento: '2005'
    }
  ];
```

En tu html lo que tienes que hacer en un `ngFor` en una tabla para cada dato de esta forma:

```html
<table *ngFor="let dato of lst">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Nombre Autor</th>
    <th>Anio</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <td>{{dato.nombre}}</td>
  <td>{{dato.nacimiento}}</td>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Como resultado de esto te da lo que estas buscando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas Gracias Fernando, me funciono muy bien